# differential_drive base_width

Tags: ros, differential-drive, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where exactly should the measurement for base width start and stop for the *differential_drive* *twist_to_motors* and *diff_tf* param? Should it be the **inside, middle, or outside** of the tires? My wheels are about 10 cm wide so there's a decent difference between these numbers. Wondering if anyone has a *definitive* answer. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324698/differential_drive-base_width/) by [billqd](https://answers.ros.org/users/37883/billqd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `differential_drive` package implements a simple, generic differential drive model. What the width between the wheels should be in this model depends on what shape your wheels are in cross-section. In other words, you want to provide the distance between the points on the wheel that will most often be in contact with the ground.

- The most common case is wheels that are symmetric, e.g. common caster wheels and car tyres. In this case, the wheel may be slightly rounded, so you can use the middle of the wheel as the point to measure from, or it may be flat, in which case the middle provides a good average.
- The wheel may be assymmetric, such as a wheel that is cambered in some way to give nice cornering. (I think this type of wheel is unlikely in a differential drive system, but it's not inconceivable.) Think of a wheel shaped like a cone. You would then measure from the wide part of the cone because that is the part that is most often in touch with the  ground.

Because you said your wheels are 10 cm wide, I'm guessing that they are thick, relatively flat tyres, so measure from the centre.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2019-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billqd](https://answers.ros.org/users/37883/billqd/) on 2019-06-04**:
Thanks. That's what I was looking for